# rack-timeout: turn off info/active logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rack

With the [rack-timeout](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout) gem installed how is it possible to display ERROR only related logs? For example I would like to avoid having the below in my logs:

`source=rack-timeout id=8a11a8ac3dadb59a4f347d8e365faddf timeout=20000ms service=0ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=8a11a8ac3dadb59a4f347d8e365faddf timeout=20000ms service=49ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=ee947d4a291d02821ab108c4c127f555 timeout=20000ms state=ready`

The following did not work:
`Rack::Timeout.unregister_state_change_observer(:active)`

The below may be on the right path but I'm having trouble testing:

`Rack::Timeout::Logger.level  = Logger::ERROR`

Answer (score 6):

(Note the class name was changed from `Stage…` to `State…` in v0.3.0)

In production I want to log at `INFO` level so I get a log message per request, but I don't want this noise from rack-timeout.

You can alter the `STATE_LOG_LEVEL` hash in the `StateChangeLoggingObserver` and change the log level used for the different states. I use this in my initialiser to prevent the `ready` and `completed` logs from showing:

```
Rack::Timeout::StateChangeLoggingObserver::STATE_LOG_LEVEL[:ready] = :debug
Rack::Timeout::StateChangeLoggingObserver::STATE_LOG_LEVEL[:completed] = :debug
```

Answer (score 5):

In `config/initializers/rack_timeout.rb` I added:

```
Rack::Timeout::Logger.disable if Rails.env.development?
```

More detailed options are described here: https://github.com/sharpstone/rack-timeout/blob/master/doc/logging.md

(Thanks @Sandip Subedi for the suggestion)

Comment: This is what I did `Rack::Timeout::Logger.disable if Rails.env.development?`

Answer (score 4):

My solution to this problem was to give `rack-timeout` its own logger.

Once you've done that, you can change its log level:

```
# config/initializers/timeout.rb
Rack::Timeout::Logger.logger = Logger.new("log/timeout.log")
Rack::Timeout::Logger.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
```

Comment: If you are deploying your app to Heroku you cannot write to `log/` so use `Rack::Timeout::Logger.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` (or stderr if you prefer) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Read here for more information

https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout#rails-apps-manually
or
https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout/blob/master/doc/settings.md

You could also try this code, though untested.

```
Rack::Timeout::StageChangeLoggingObserver.logger = logger = ::Logger.new(STDERR)
logger.level = ::Logger::DEBUG
logger.formatter = ->(severity, timestamp, progname, msg) {"[#{timestamp}] #{msg} at=#{severity.downcase}\n" }
```