# Rails 3 upgrade to 4 assets causing Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I have taken over a rails app that is in the process of upgrading from 3.2. The problem is that the assets take too long.

**Update:**
This issue is happening in development.

[image: Rack Timeout]

Here is the base_theme.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.fileupload
//= require legacy.jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery.color
//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require jquery.mask
//= require jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min
//= require history.adapter.jquery
//= require history
//= require bootstrap.min.js
// require bootstrap
//= require affix
//= require scrollspy
//= require webcam
//= require onfido.min
//= require ce-compliance-action-invest
//= require ce-compliance-investment-slider
//= require ce-investment-fee-calculator
//= require ce-direct-uploads
//= require ce-image-processor
//= require ce-country-states
//= require ce-modal
//= require ce-camera
//= require ce-session-timeout
//= require ce-project-duplicator
//= require payment_methods
//= require projects
//= require test_the_waters_project
//= require base-script
//= require Chart
//= require social-share-kit.min
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require md-slider.min.js
// require tabs
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require ckeditor/config
//= require front-end-validation-helper
//= require jquery.validate.min.js
//= require jquery.bootstrap.wizard
//= require vimeo-player
//= require bs-wizard
//= require rewards-checkout-validation
//= require mask_and_reveal.js
//= require team_members.js
```

The app has a lot of liquid in it as in it has very few true rails way ™  views. It's not just the javascript files on other pages it will fail to load on the `style_sheet_tag`.

I'm not sure if I'm missing a step where rails 4.x deprecated a gem or a configuration for the assets. Below is from the application.rb file

[image: application.rb]

**Update:**
Like I said this app has a lot of liquid for this particular issue it's happening on the line below. Other times this comes up it's not doing this render_to_string, and oddly enough the render_to_string is coming from WickedPDF.

```
@compressed_js = render_to_string partial: 'application/compressed_js_assets'
```

Comment: Try setting `config.assets.debug = false` in `config/development.rb` (or in whichever environment file you're using). [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50868102/3784008).

Comment: I had similar error in process of deploying app with mina gem and the problem solution in my case was first to stop running site puma server and then run on production server or development which ever env you have issue: "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" after that deployment worked well without error.

Comment: @anothermh I have set that to false and still had the same issue

Comment: @Nezir unfortunately this is in development haven't even gotten to a point to be able to deploy it to staging.

Comment: so you have that error when running rails s on local dev?

Comment: @Nezir yes this error is when running rails server local. Prior to the upgrade there is a comment on setting the rack timeout limit saying that some places are slow. But on the rails 4 upgrade branch it is unusable.

Comment: You obviously have  gem "rack-timeout" in gemfile? did you tried to comment it and run bundle after and then rails s?

Comment: @Nezir I haven't tried that yet because I wanted to get to the bottom of the issue why the assets are taking so long. I can do that and see but I think it will just be the app sitting there spinning forever. I will report back.

Comment: then try to check logs for anything suspicious here is example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030781/rack-timeout-turn-off-info-active-logging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180686/discussion-between-covard-and-nezir).